# Performance Issues .Net Core 5 MVC

Tags: .net, http, asp.net-core, https, kestrel-http-server

I have created a .net core 5 web application that talks to a Sql server. I am having issues on getting proper response times from the Kestrel server. My database call completes in less than a second and the controller tries to pass the data to the view. It is here the requests hangs for ~7 seconds average for a payload of only 195kb.

**Network monitor window**
[image: Network Monitor window from chrome]

**Performance Window Chrome**
[image: Chrome performance window]

**Call Stack from the controller**
[image: Call Stack]

Comment: I have figured out the root cause, however I still do not have a solution. Upon injecting System.Diagnostics timer into my view I found the actual creation of the page is taking 7.5 seconds for 5000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out using @Html.DisplayFor within a for loop is EXTREMELY slow in the Razor view engine. Removing @Html.DisplayFor and outputting values directly solved my problem. Once removed building the page took .1 second.

**Load time after I removed DisplayFor**
[image: New load times]